# ManyToManyField In HTML

Tags: python, django

Can someone please let me know the proper way to display values that have been entered in a ManyToMany data field?

In my project, a contractor can have multiple trades or skills, this should be entered in the **trade** field.

```
class SubTrade(models.Model):
strade = models.CharField("Trade", max_length=255)
def __str__(self):
    return self.strade
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse ("trade_full", kwargs={"pk": self.id})


class SubContractor(models.Model):
nameF = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
nameL = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
nameN = models.CharField("Nickname", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
trade = models.ManyToManyField('SubTrade')
phone = models.CharField("Phone", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
email = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=254, blank = True, null = True)
address = models.CharField("Address", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
dateC = models.DateTimeField("Date Created", auto_now_add=True)
dateU = models.DateTimeField("Last Updated", auto_now=True)
note = models.TextField("Notes",  blank = True, null = True)
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.nameF, self.nameL)
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse ("contractor_full", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
```

These are my views.

```
class SubContractorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = SubContractor
    template_name = "project/contractoradd.html"
    fields = ['nameF', 'nameL', 'nameN', 'trade', 'address', 'phone', 'email', 'note']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is my HTML Code

```
{% for contractor in contractor %}
 Last Name: {{contractor.nameL}}
 <br>
 Trade: {{contractor.trade}}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my HTML output

```
Last Name: Piper
Trade: project.SubTrade.None
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `join` [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join)

```
{% for contractor in contractor %}
    Last Name: {{contractor.nameL}}
    <br>
    Trade: {{ contractor.trade.all|join:", " }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or with iteration:

```
{% for contractor in contractor %}
    Last Name: {{contractor.nameL}}
    <br>
    Trade: {% for trade in contractor.trade.all %}{{ trade.strade }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

See [Accessing method calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls)

Comment: Thank You so much!! Can you please share a link with documentation for this?

Comment: @marcm1992, Happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer, or any other answer, helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. See [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)